# How to output 1 bit audio at a specific sample rate in python?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi4

I'm reading in a wav file using

```
from scipy.io import wavfile
samplerate, data = wavfile.read('rick.wav')
```

I am then reading the left channel using the first column, and setting the output of my speaker to be on or off based off the sign of the data (ie converting to one bit audio)

```
for d in data:
    GPIO.output(piezoOutPin, d[0] > 0)
```

This works, but the sample rate is all over the place. Any suggestions for forcing this to output at a constant 48khz sample rate or whatever sample rate the file is?

Comment: I doubt that you'll get good timing with Python. Python can't even output a PWM signal reliably (at least to my codings so far), since it will be interrupted from time to time by other processes,

Comment: @ThomasWeller I'm playing 1 bit audio, I don't really need perfect timing, just would like to try to get something closer than what I'm getting right now